# Can I cross develop an app for IIS and Azure?

Tags: iis, azure

We are starting to build out some new tech and I want to know if it is possible to cross develop a web app to run natively in Azure (ie, use Azure specific stuff like storage) but also run locally on our test servers and accommodate internal deployments natively on IIS?

I know I can host them from a dev box in a simulated Azure environment and I know that I can interface the Azure parts out and write in non-azure counterparts.  It just seems like this should be a solved problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run Azure applications on-premises (*and using non-development Azure storage*), you must run a [Microsoft Private Cloud](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/private-cloud/). It requires special hardware and licensing costs, so don't expect it to run on what you have today.

Comment: This may be the way to go.  I am contacting a reseller to get pricing and details.

Comment: Just to be clear: There is no Windows Azure Storage equivalent that runs locally in a private cloud. If you want Blobs, Tables and Queues, they will be in Windows Azure (the public cloud). And you can access Windows Azure Storage from any server or language, as it's REST-based. No need for a Microsoft Private Cloud.

Comment: @DavidMakogon - is this the same for SQL Azure? Is the only benefit for private clouds now just having Azure roles (Web, Worker, & VM)?

Comment: Right - SQL Azure is specifically in the public cloud. SQL Azure database code should work fine in SQL Server on-premises, so that should be pretty seamless.

Comment: @David, with one exception - SQL Azure Federations is currently only supported in SQL Azure. As by today, there is no SQL Server Federations, if my memory does not cheat me.

Comment: @Anton - good point. :)  Especially since Federations are now RTW.

Comment: Answer: I can't seem to find any other solutions and this one isn't that bad.